# Como comprobar que todos los valores de un array sean iguales php

Tags: php

¿Como comprobar que todos los valores de un array sean iguales php?
He estado intentando con el siguiente código:

```
$array = "1,1,1,2,1";
$array = explode(",",$array);
$val = 2;
foreach($array as $value) {
    if($value=="3") {
        $val =  "3";
    } elseif($value=="1") {
        $val =  "1";
    } elseif($value=="0") {
        $val =  "1";
    } elseif($value=="5") {
        $val =  "1";
    }
}
return $val;
```

**Lo que intento hacer:**

- Si todos los valores del array sean iguales a 1 me retorne 1.
- Si en el array están presentes los números 1,2,5,0 me retorne 1.
- Si todos los valores del array son iguales a 5 me retorne 2.
- Si todos los valores del array son iguales a 0 me retorne 0.
- Si cualquier valor del array es igual a 3 me retorne 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se me ocurre `contar` la presencia de los valores del arreglo, para luego verificar cual es el valor a retornar.

Sino se cumple ninguna de las condiciones retorno `-1` por defecto.

```
$array = [1,1,1,2,1];

echo verificarArray($array);

function verificarArray($array) {
    $contCero = $contUno = $contDos = $contTres = $contCinco = 0;
    $valorRetorno = -1;
    foreach($array as $value) {
        switch ($value)
        {
        case 0:
            $contCero++;
            break;
        case 1:
            $contUno++;
            break;
        case 2:
            $contDos++;
            break;
        case 3:
            $contTres++;
            break;
        case 5:
            $contCinco++;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($contTres > 0) {  // Si esta presente al menos una vez el numero 3
        $valorRetorno = 3;
    } else if ($contUno === 5 || ($contCero > 0 && $contUno > 0 && $contDos > 0 && $contCinco > 0)) {  // Si todos los números son 1 o si al menos hay un 0,1,2,5
        $valorRetorno = 1;
    } else if ($contCinco === 5) {  // Si todos los números son 5
        $valorRetorno = 2;
    } else if ($contCero === 5) {  // Si todos los números son 0
        $valorRetorno = 0;
    }

    return $valorRetorno;

}
```

Al final se imprime `-1` para ese <kbd>array</kbd> de ejemplo

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio de 10!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar `array_unique` para reducir tu <kbd>array</kbd> a valores no repetidos, y con `count` comprobar cuántos elementos tiene el nuevo <kbd>array</kbd>, en caso de ser 1 compruebas el valor y en caso de ser mayor compruebas las condiciones para valores distintos.

```
$aunico = array_unique($array);
$n =count($aunico);
if ($n==1){
  if (in_array(0,$aunico)) { $val=0; }
  else if (in_array(1,$aunico)) { $val=1; }
  else if (in_array(3,$aunico))  { $val=3; }
  else { $val=2; } //valor x defecto o si todos los elementos son 5
} else if ($n==4) {
  if (in_array(0,$aunico) && in_array(1,$aunico) && in_array(2,$aunico) && in_array(5,$aunico)) { $val=1; }
  else { $val=2; }
} else {
// valor por defecto
  $val=2;
}
```